Applying for F2 visa for my 2nd wife
I got married for the first time in 2021 in Bangladesh but later I didn’t have good understanding with my first wife. In 2022 I came to US for starting my PhD in Fall 22 but I didn’t take my 1st wife as my dependent or F2. And finally I got divorced from her in September 2023. After that I didn’t have any relation or marriage with anyone. Recently, in the month of June 2024 I went to Bangladesh for vacation and then I got married for the 2nd time. Now I want to apply for my 2nd wife’s F2 visa to bring her US . But the problem is when I renewed my Bangladeshi passport in 2022, that time I was married to the 1st wife so that in my passport her name is mentioned as spouse name.
My question is : Will my passport’s spouse info need to be updated before my 2nd wife goes for F2 visa application and interview at US embassy or is it okay if my 2nd wife goes with F2 i-20 and marriage documents as proof for the visa interview? I need to mention that I have the documents of proof of my divorce as well as the marriage certificate registered in Bangladesh.

You'd need to provide the documents of your divorce, but other than that should be fine. Not entirely sure why your wife's name is mentioned in your passport at all...

@littleadv it's fairly common from what I can tell.  It seems to be a holdover from the dark ages in which a married woman had no independent legal existence in many systems and a family traveling together could do so by virtue of being mentioned in the husband's/father's passport.  Very few countries if any permit this these days, but some will still list family members as supplementary information.
